# How to fix 'jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time' or "The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port."in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I get an error when I use jupyter-notebook in vs-code with the newest python extension. After creating a new blank jyupter notebook with easy command every time I failed to launch jyupyter server. The error hint is 'Error: The Jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time [I 23:22:42.012 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.' or 'jupyter notebook server failed to launch in time' and nothing displayed in the debug console.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey ualia Q. I can help here, since I watch Stack Overflow myself. But if you want to file this issue on our GitHub issues page that is where we track our issues so that's probably the best spot.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Two questions that could help me diagnose this:
1. Can you start up a terminal / command prompt with the python environment that you are using in VSCode and run jupyter notebook from the command line?
2. Could you paste here the output of the Help->Toggle Developer Tools console log? That has more diagnostics info that can be useful.

Comment: @lan Huff Thanks for your reply and I will file this question on the issue page in your reply with the respond of your questions. Wish vs code will be better!